Bellard's formula always generates 3.14506
I've been working on a simple C++ program to approximate pi with Bellard's formula. No matter what number of digits it tries calculating to, it results in the number 3.145063.
I tried changing it from storing as a float to a double, because I thought it might just be rounding to fit in the smaller data type, but it still isn't working.
Here's my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double approximate(int digits) {
    double summed = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < digits; n++) {
        summed += (pow(-1, n) / pow(2, n * 10)) * ((-(pow(2, 5)) / (4 * n + 1)) - (1 / (4 * n + 3)) + (pow(2, 8) / (10 * n + 1)) - (pow(2, 6) / (10 * n + 3)) - (pow(2, 2) / (10 * n + 5)) - (pow(2, 2) / (10 * n + 7)) + (1 / (10 * n + 9)));
    }
    return (1 / pow(2, 6)) * summed;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "How many digits?: ";
    std::string its;
    std::getline(std::cin, its);
    std::string approx = std::to_string(approximate(std::stoi(its)));
    std::cout << approx << std::endl;
}


It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: How to debug small programs and Debugging Guide

summed += -- Instead of that terribly long line of code, break it up into several lines to see which calculation is not what you expect.  And yes, use a debugger.

1 / (10 * n + 9) - This is integer division.  An int divided by an int will give you an int.  But again, if you had broken that line up, you would have seen this issue.

Side note: Compilers are getting smarter and might catch this bit of overkill, but pow(-1, n) to flip a sign bit is grossly expensive if the compiler doesn't catch on. pow is a nasty thing designed to handle the bad mother ers like computing pi to the power of e.  If you are flipping a bit pow(-1, n), moving a bit pow(2,n), or performing a simple squaring pow(x,2) you may find that the program's doing way more work than using a look-up table, a bit shift, or multiplication.

Side note: again, compilers are getting smart and may spot that pow(2, 5) never changes and cache the result or possibly even compute it at compile time and turn it into a constant. But check all the same.

And don't forget to test for no-or-bad input: https://godbolt.org/z/jf6xv4nqT

As mentioned, if you had broken the line up into several statements, you would have seen that you are performing integer division instead of floating point division.
(1 / (4 * n + 3)) and
(1 / (10 * n + 9))
are not correct.  The simple correction is to use 1.0 to force a floating point division to occur:
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double approximate(int digits) {
    double summed = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < digits; n++) {
        summed += (pow(-1, n) / pow(2, n * 10)) * 
                  ((-(pow(2, 5)) / (4 * n + 1)) - (1.0 / (4 * n + 3)) + // <-- 1.0
                  (pow(2, 8) / (10 * n + 1)) - 
                  (pow(2, 6) / (10 * n + 3)) - 
                  (pow(2, 2) / (10 * n + 5)) - 
                  (pow(2, 2) / (10 * n + 7)) + (1.0 / (10 * n + 9))); // <-- 1.0
    }
    return (1 / pow(2, 6)) * summed;
}

int main() {
    std::string approx = std::to_string(approximate(10));
    std::cout << approx << std::endl;
}

Output:
3.141593

The other things in your code that can also be improved, more specifically, are the calls to pow.  You know that pow(2,2), pow(2,5), pow(2,8), pow(2,6), (1.0 / pow(2,6)), etc. are constants.  They do not be need to be computed each and every time the forloop iterates, or at thereturn` point.  Just make these floating point constants and use them.

Edit:
Here is a compile-time version of your code, which can calculate to a maximum of 6 digits of precision.
Note that the assembly output doesn't have any trace of the approximate function call anywhere, as the entire value was computed at compile-time.

Thanks, this works. The only problem is that the result seems to stay the same no matter the number of digits inputted, but that's a whole other problem I think.

@JakeStBu Remember that the algorithm isn’t computing one digit at a time, but guaranteeing that N digits are correct. After about N=5 you aren’t going to see any difference in the computation of the first 10 or so digits.
